# PHP: Use parent namespace by default in child namespaced class

Tags: php, namespaces

For example my root namespace is `myns` where are all helper classes. There is `myns\controllers` namespace where are all the controllers.

I want to use `myns` namespace by default in all `myns\controllers` classes, avoiding many

`use myns\classname;`

declarations at the beginning.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

No. The "default namespace" is established by `namespace`, not `use`. You have two options:

1. Switch the namespace:

   ```
   namespace myns\controllers {
       class Foo {}
   }

   namespace myns {
       use myns\controllers\Foo;

       new Foo;  // above Foo class
       new Bar;  // myns\Bar class
   }
   ```
2. `Use` a shortened handle:

   ```
   use myns as m;

   new m\Bar;  // myns\Bar
   ```

Practically speaking, in sane code, you shouldn't be having *a ton* of stuff from other namespaces that you're going to `use`; explicitly aliasing a small handful (say, up to around a dozen) of functions and classes at the top of the file is pretty normal. A decent IDE can pretty much auto-generate those `use` statements as you type.

Comment: Yes I know that IDEs could make my life easier, but I think it will be a great feature.